# Is there any name customarily associated with Siva/Rudra that Vaishnavites would not claim also applies to Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, shiva

They seem to claim that Satarudriyam is dedicated to Vishnu or Narasimha (but i doubt if they would recite it).  Rudra and Siva are of course names of Vishnu in the Vishnusahasranama.

Svetasvatara upanishad is full of names of Siva, but they claim it applies to a Vaishnavite figure (I forget which one) (although there are non-sectarian claims that it doesn't apply to any personal deity).

Perhaps Pinaki or Pinakapani is something they would concede exclusively to Siva?

Comment: No name is exclusively conceded to Shiva. Given any name X of Shiva, it is applied to Vishnu by interpreting X as "inner controller of X" = Vishnu.

Comment: @Lazy Lubber - but he is NOT the controller when alleged "Tamasic tendencies overcome Siva", right?  Which means anything good - it is done by the inner Vishnu, but anything bad is due to Tamas, right?  This non-falsifiable logic, according to Karl Popper.

Comment: whenever it is convenient. For example if scripture says "Shiva is supreme", it is interpreted as "inner controller of Shiva = Vishnu is supreme". But if scripture says "Shiva was defeated in the battle", then it is interpreted as it is.

Comment: No saMskrit name is proper noun. Most of the names are adjectives & are just to refer. Read [this](https://uttishthabharata.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/sanskrit/)

Comment: @Mr. Sigma. fascinating.  But Vaishnavites have long claimed that Panini's grammar makes "Narayana" a proper noun that can only denote the Vaishnavite God.  It is said that even Appayya Diksihta was stumped by it.  But things like a "satvika" purana (I think "varaha") calling Siva "narayana" and modern linguistic analysis has cooled them down and they don't claim it much any more.

Comment: @SK Narayana being a proper noun is not accepted by non-vaishnavas.

Comment: @LazyLubber "whenever it is convenient." - It is **not** whenever it is "convenient." It is grounded in sound logic. Narayana is a proper noun, according to Panini, because of the "Na" in the name. All other words like Shiva, Isha, Vishnu, etc are merely normal nouns. Even Appayya Dikshita, the great Shaiva scholar, has accepted this. Depending on the context, Shiva can mean the actual deity known as Shiva, or it can mean Narayana if you take "Shiva" as an adjective, or if the verse is really referring to Shiva, then it can refer to Narayana as the Antaryami through Samanadhikaranya.

Comment: @LazyLubber If a verse says "Narayana created the universe," and another verse says "Shiva created the universe," then "Shiva" in that verse refers to Narayana, because Narayana is a proper noun and Shiva is a common noun.

Comment: The sanskrit dictionary includes even Shiva in meaning of Naraayana. And there are so many words like Trishuli, Gangadhara, Pashpati, Vrishavahana, Pramathanatha, Madananantaka etc etc that mean only Shiva. What exactly is your question, sorry I could not get:)